# Select element in one list based on the position of n item in another list

Tags: python

```
title = ['james','tom','kim']
post_id = [5,6,9]
what_to_look = ['tom','kim']

x = title == post_id

if what_to_look  == x:
    print('find')
else:
    print('not found')
```

Hi guys how to get the id 6 in this code? what is wrong why is not working?

Comment: look at `enumerate` function

Comment: `title` and `post_id` are different objects, so `title == post_id` will always evaluate to `False`, so `x` will always be `False`, so `x == what_to_look` will never be true. Try either the `zip` or `index` functions, like a new variable `look_index=title.index(what_to_look)` to get the index where your string occurs in the list, then use that to index into your id list

Comment: Why are you using separate lists? If you need to map between values, use a dictionary.

Comment: sorry guys im very beginner in this field but if you help me thank you

Comment: Do you want to get 'tom'? using id 6?

Comment: @Shounak Das hello yes i want to get the value 6

Comment: Do you know what *x = title == post_id* does? Given the data shown in your question it will be assigned False - which is probably not what you wanted or expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `post_id` by the respective title you can use `.index()` method. You can follow the algorithm:

1. Find if `What_to_look` is in your `title` list
2. if yes, get the index of it using `.index()` method.
3. get the element at the same position of `post_id` list.

so Your final code should be:

```
title = ['james','tom','kim']
post_ids = [5,6,9]
what_to_look = input('Enter Name: ')

if what_to_look in title:
    position = title.index(what_to_look)
    post_id = post_ids[position]
    print('found', post_id)
else:
    print('not found')
```

Now you can get id 6 by entering 'tom'

Comment: Credits are due to Shounak Das, I just edited some unfortunately named variables ;-)

Comment: How about bro using while? can you give me example?

Comment: Ofcourse,  so you want to loop it continuously?

Comment: YES PLEASE i want to loop repeated until ending @Shounak Das

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` function as follows:

```
title = ['james','tom','kim']
post_id = [5,6,9]
title_id = list(zip(title, post_id))
what_to_look = input('Enter Name: ')
for i in title_id:
    if i[0] == what_to_look:
        print(f"found. id = {i[1]}")
        break
else:   # it is for-else not if-else condition
    print("not found")
```

input: james

output: found. id = 5

(Notice that using a dictionary will be much better and more efficient)

Comment: Bro can you do it on a while loop instead of if?

Comment: Great example for `for-else`.

Answer (score 0):

Given two lists of equal length you can use *zip()*. (Actually the lists don't have to be the same length but let's keep it simple)

```
title = ['james','tom','Kim']
post_id = [5,6,9]

query = input('Enter name: ')

for name, pid in zip(title, post_id):
    if name == query:
        print(pid)
        break
else:
    print('Not found')
```

Alternatively, convert your lists into a single dictionary then you can do a direct lookup as follows:

```
title = ['james','tom','Kim']
post_id = [5,6,9]

query = input('Enter name: ')

print(dict(zip(title, post_id)).get(query, 'Not found'))
```

Comment: bro im very gad you commented can you do it for a while loop?

Comment: @LegendCoder What is the *while* condition?

Comment: Can you do it with this? what_to_look = ('tom','kim') instead of manual input of every item i want to list it on a single lists so it will easily find..